# how can i solve the gcc problems in Debian ? when i am apt-get install gcc find one qustions?

Tags: gcc, debian

I'm using `gcc` to compile files in Debian terminal,
but I get back : `zsh: command not found: gcc`

So I've tried `sudo apt-get install gcc`.

```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> gcc :
> Depends:gcc-4.7(>=4.7.2-1~) but it is not going to be installed
> Recommends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or libc-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing GCC and its dependencies with this package:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: turn back 
`build-essential :Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or libc-dev` 
-------

`Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your apt packet manager. I'm sorry, I can't help you right now but googling "depends but it is not going to be installed" might help you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command:

```
aptitude -f install
```

Then install `build-essantial` it will install all the dev-tools:

```
aptitude install build-essential
```